# How to get the derivative of $F(a(x,y,t),b(x,y,t))$ wrt $t$ displayed as $f(x,y,t)(dF/dx) + g(x,y,t)(dF/dx)$?

Tags: derivatives, calculus

I have a function $F(a(x,y,t),b(x,y,t))$ whose derivative wrt t I would like to write as

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} = f(x,y,t)\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} + g(x,y,t)\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}
$$

I'm reaching

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} = f(x,y,t)\frac{\partial F}{\partial a} + g(x,y,t)\frac{\partial F}{\partial b}
$$

but after this, I cannot seem to convert $\frac{\partial F}{\partial a}$ to $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$. For instance, $a(x,y) = x\cos t + y \sin t$. I am taking $x =\frac{a-y\sin t}{\cos t}$ and then taking $\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}$ to substitute in $\frac{\partial F}{\partial a} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial a}$. On doing the same for $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$ and getting an expression, upon putting $F$ back in the equation and checking, equality does not hold.

What am I doing wrong? My function is

$$F(a(x,y,t),b(x,y,t)) = F(x\cos t + y\sin t, x\sin t + y\cos t)$$

Any insight appreciated.

Comment: Why aren't you considering any derivatives with respect to $t$? I thought $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial t}$$

Comment: What does $\partial F/\partial x$ even mean? $F$ is not a function of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding you, I don't think you can do what you want in general. In determining $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}$ we are assuming $x$ and $y$ are constant. Therefore, the partial derivative you are looking at should not have any explicit dependence on $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ or $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$. Using the chain rule, we have

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial
a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial t}$$

In general
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial a}\neq\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$$